# How to get the path of a OneDrive Link?

Tags: path, onedrive, hyperlink

In **OneDrive** we are able to share files via a **Link**.

However often I want to know the path / location of the file 
So I do not need to get the link (which somebody sent me) but can navigate in OneDrive to the file.

How can I do that?

Note: A coworker shared a folder called _Public
**Now I want to know the directory in which the file is saved.**

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't; I'm pretty sure that is by design. OneDrive uses [id based addressing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems?view=odsp-graph-online#id-based-addressing), if you received a link to a folder, you can see files and folders below that folder in a hierarchy, but not above it.

Details from developer-level documentation:

## ID-based addressing

OneDrive supports ID-based addressing of items. Items are assigned a unique identifier when they are created and the ID persists across the actions a user performs on the item. Renaming or moving the item will not change the item's ID.

ID-based addressing is a useful way to track items that might be moved by the user to different locations on OneDrive. As long as you have the item's ID and the item exists, you'll be able to find it.

## Path-based addressing

OneDrive also supports path-based addressing. This allows you to use a friendly URL syntax to address items relative to the hierarchy of items visible in OneDrive. If you know the hierarchy to an item, you can directly address that item, without spending any time making repeated calls to discover each level of the hierarchy.

However, since path-based addressing is based on the name of the item, renaming or moving the item to a new location will cause the path of the item to change.

Path-based addressing can be used relative to any item in OneDrive, which enables some very useful scenarios. For example, when working with shared folders, you can use a path-based URL relative to the shared folder's item ID to address something in the shared folder by path.